# Geometry Lines Display

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

The shown image below got province lines, this is at a zoom of 7. However; if I zoom out to 6, these province lines disappear.

[image: Province Lines at Zoom 7.]

[image: No Province Lines at Zoom 6.]

Is there any way to get these lines, even at Zoom 6? I've tried via the Style Wizard: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html?utm_medium=twitter, but without luck..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one option would be to remove all the province lines from the styled map.  Add them in with a FusionTablesLayer or KmlLayer.

Comment: @Downvoter: Explain why U did that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option would be to remove all the province lines from the styled map. Add them in with a FusionTablesLayer or KmlLayer

```
var stateBorders = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'kml_4326',
        from: '19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA'
    },
    map: map,
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
            fillOpacity: 0.001,
            strokeColor: "000000",
            strokeWeight: 1,
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            fillColor: "FFFFFF"
        }
    }]
});
```

[Proof of concept fiddle using FusionTablesLayer](http://jsfiddle.net/yn4earpm/3/)